# Addition of polynomial functions

Tags: arrays, c, function, addition, polynomials

I need help solving this problem, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

The task is:
Write a program that loads two polynomials and then calculates and prints their sum, with structure POLYNOMIAL and functions: `POLYNOMIAL load();`,`POLYNOMIAL add(POLYNOMIAL,POLYNOMIAL);`, `void prints(POLYNOMIAL);`.

```
For example:
Enter the degree of the polynomial:2
Enter coefficients:
a[0]=1
a[1]=2
a[2]=3
Enter the degree of the polynomial:3
Enter coefficients:
a[0]=1
a[1]=2
a[2]=3
a[3]=4
Output is:4x^3+6x^2+4x+2
```

I did it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 100

typedef struct polynomial
{
  int coefficient[MAX],degree;
}POLYNOMIAL;

POLYNOMIAL load();
POLYNOMIAL add(POLYNOMIAL,POLYNOMIAL);
void prints(POLYNOMIAL);


int main()
{
POLYNOMIAL p1,p2,p3;
p1=load();
p2=load();
p3=add(p1,p2);
prints(p3);
return 0;

}
POLYNOMIAL load()
{
POLYNOMIAL p;
printf("Enter degree of polynomial:");
scanf("%d",&p.degree);
while(p.degree<1 || p.degree>MAX)
{
   printf("Enter degree of polynomial:");
    scanf("%d",&p.degree);
}

printf("Enter coefficients of polynomial:\n");
for(int i=0;i<=p.degree;i++)
{
    printf("a[%d]=",i);
    scanf("%d",&p.coefficient[i]);
}

return p;

}
POLYNOMIAL add(POLYNOMIAL p1,POLYNOMIAL p2)
{
POLYNOMIAL sum;

for(int i=0;i<=p1.degree;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=p2.degree;j++)
    {
       sum.coefficient[i]=p1.coefficient[i]+p2.coefficient[j];
       return sum;

    }
}
}
void prints(POLYNOMIAL p1)
{
for(int i=p1.degree;i>=0;i--)
{
    printf("%d",p1.coefficient[i]);
    if(i!=0)
    {
       printf("x^%d",i);
    }
    if(i!=0)
    {
        printf("+");

    }
}
}
```

What is a problem for me is that I can't add these two polynomials, I can't set the function to work properly.
When I enter the degrees and coefficients of the polynomial, the program does not print anything, it just ends.
If anyone can help me solve this problem I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including sample input that reproduces the problem, the observed output, and the desired output.

Comment: Your return statement is inside the loop.  You need to return after the calculation is completed.

Comment: Explain the `add` function to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (or suitable substitute, like room-mate, significant other, or your pet). Also less than a minute stepping through the code in a debugger would also have told you the problem.

Comment: The `add` function doesn't seem to be correct. A function which only adds two polynomials shouldn't have nested loops.